# What happens if the return value can't fit in EAX?

Tags: x86, calling-convention

Let's assume that the return value can't fit in `EAX` register. What can the compiler do to return the value?

One thing that's come up to my mind is storing that value into memory and putting the address of that memory in `EAX`, but that's okay and will work but the problem here is how to indicate to the one that is receiving the value (stored in EAX) that this is not a value but rather a pointer in memory to the actual value.

Comment: This is entirely defined by the calling convention. The calling convention will tell you how to handle return values that don't fit into the size of the return register. So the question is which calling convention are we talking about? I assume 32-bits? Windows? Linux/MacOS/BSD? The compiler will generate code to handle the return values per the calling convention requirements. In many of the 32-bit conventions when dealing with the size of a type that can't fit in a 32-bit register, the caller is required to pass the address to hold the return value as one of the parameters.

Comment: Let's say I'm interested in cdecl and stdcall, fastcall

Comment: The problem is that cdecl can be different on different platforms. cdecl on Windows isn't the same as cdecl on Linux. SO we need to know which calling convention. So my next question is - what platform are you looking at for `cdelc`. Windows? Linux? something else? Is this 32-bit or 64-bit code (CDECL differs between 32 and 64-bit as well)

Comment: oh I didn't know that it sound like interesting stuff to look out for later, but for now, I would stick to windows for both x64 and x32, and if you can point me to some article about Linux it would be great

Comment: Agner fog has a document that tries to detail most of the well known calling conventions including their return value rules. That can be found here: https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf . Some of the basic for 32-bit Microsoft convention can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2019 (note that with Win 32 CDECL calling convention 8 byte values are returned in EDX:EAX. Anything larger is returned in an address (to memory allocated by the caller) pushed on the stack by the caller as a hidden parameter.

Comment: The latest ABIs for Linux (32-bit and AMD64) can be found here: https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI  . There is also valuable info in the [x86] tag decription on Stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: On most (all?) mainstream calling conventions, the caller passes the address of the return-value object, and yes the function returns the address in the (first) return-value register, if it's too large for RDX:RAX or EDX:EAX, or just EAX depending on the convention.